# How can SysVinit scripts restart after their dependencies restart

Tags: linux, init

SysVinit scripts can declare dependencies with `Required-Start` and `Required-Stop`:

```
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          my-containerized-service
# Required-Start:    docker
# Required-Stop:     docker
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:      0 1 6
### END INIT INFO
```

After symlinking this script into `/etc/rc3.d` it will automatically start up after docker when the system comes up. But if I manually restart docker, `my-containerized-service` is stopped, but it does not get restarted. Is there some way to register an event that listens for docker restarts and then starts up my service.

Comment: Not with SysVinit.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.